# force webpage cursor

Tags: html, css, cross-browser, cursor

According to [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_class_cursor.asp)

> The cursor property specifies the type
>   of cursor to be displayed when
>   pointing on an element.

However I found an elements cursor is not shown under certain browsers when working with a rich text editor, which uses an iframe. Firefox/Chrome/Safari/Konqueror work but IE/Opera do not.

Is there a way to reliably set the cursor in this case across all browsers? For example a way to set the cursor independent of which element is pointed at.

***Edit:
the cursor style is set on elements within the iframe. This works except that IE/Opera can't seem to detect hover events properly within the iframe.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe something like this would work in your stylesheet:

```
* { cursor:pointer!important; }
```

I also suspect you might have to apply a rule like this within the style of the text editor's frame. You should read the documentation of the editor for instructions on how to do it.

Comment: Given the nature/phrasing of the question this may be a valid answer... but normally I'd point out that under most circumstances using `!important` is a bad idea and instead one should use CSS specificity http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#specificity

Answer (score 0):

Given that the WYSIWYG editor uses an `<iframe>` and an `<iframe>` is its own document, your CSS won't doesn't apply to the contents of the `<iframe>`.

When you use an `<iframe>` the resulting DOM structure looks a little like this...

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>iframe example</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="outer.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            The contents of the outer document!
            <iframe>
                <html>
                    <head>
                        <title>iframe example</title>
                        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="inner.css" />
                    </head>
                    <body>
                        <div>
                            The Contents of the iFrame!
                        </div>
                    </body>
                </html>
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

... and the rules defined in `outer.css` don't apply to the contents of the `<iframe>`, and the contents of `inner.css` don't apply to the outer document.

Comment: yes I am applying the style within the iframe. That is why my solution works in most browsers...

Comment: Ahhh, good point; I missed the part where it works in most browsers. My bad! :)